# Floating point number rounded automatically

Tags: c#

Decimal numbers can not be exactly converted to a floating point number format actually.
As many of you know, because there are not big enough exponent and mantissa digits in 32 bits. [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard.

So I know there could be round-off error.

For example, (I used decimal to single converter. [here](https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/))

```
0.1 => actually saved as 0.100000001490116119384765625  not 0.1
0.2 => actually saved as 0.20000000298023223876953125   not 0.2
0.3 => actually saved as 0.300000011920928955078125     not 0.3
```

But, When I assign the above floating point values to float variables, 
They are automatically changed to rounded values. code here.

```
    float a_1 = 0.300000011920928955078125f;
    float a_2 = 0.20000000298023223876953125f;
    float a_3 = 0.100000001490116119384765625f;

    Debug.Log(a_1); // result : 0.1
    Debug.Log(a_2); // result : 0.2
    Debug.Log(a_3); // result : 0.3
```

So why the long numbers (that can be save as floating point number in a byte memory) become simple rounded number (like 0.1, 0.2, 0.3)? 
Anyone can explain the internal process?

Comment: Simply the default `float.ToString()` doesn't show all the digits but only the first x decimal digits, doing a rounding.

Comment: That question is for `double`, but `single` are the same (but with less digits).

Comment: Yes, the default `ToString` rounding is responsible. Try `a_1.ToString("G9")` for example. Note that the debugger also uses the same `ToString` behavior...